# How to testing a pure javascript function with library-testing-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

```
const handlePrev = (page, setPage) => {
  if (page > 1) {
    setPage(page - 1);
  }
};

const handleNext = (page, setPage, countPage) => {
  if (page < countPage) {
    setPage(page + 1);
  }
};

const renderPageNumberButton = (page, setPage, countPage) => {
  const buttons = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= countPage; i++) {
    buttons.push(
      <button
        key={i}
        className={`${
          i === page ? "bg-zinc-500 text-zinc-300" : "bg-zinc-800 text-zinc-400"
        } w-10 h-10`}
        onClick={() => setPage(i)}
      >
        {i}
      </button>,
    );
  }

  return buttons;
};

export { handlePrev, handleNext, renderPageNumberButton };
```

I want to testing this code, but if I use this testing code, nothing happened with the testing, the code line still uncovered[This is the testing I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGnt7.png)

Answer (score 0):

that's not the way you should test your code. unless you are testing some kind of validation that does not change the react state but returns a value than you shouldn't test it separately.

as for the `handlePrev` i don't know think you can test .tobecalled with that. you can test `setPage` since you are mocking it. still, i would recommend you to test the component as a whole or convert it to a custom hook and test the hook.
you can try something like

```js
let page = 1
const setPage = jest.fn();
handlePrev(page, setPage);
expect(setPage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
page  = 2
handlePrev(page, setPage);
expect(setPage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
```

here link to the react-testing-lib doc that will hopefully explain to you all.
[DocLink](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro)